# Unable to modify page number which is within dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using post requests to fetch the json content from a webpage. The script is doing just fine if I'm only stick to it's default page. However, my intention is to create a loop to collect the content from few different pages. The only problem I'm struggling to solve is use `page` keyword within `payload` in order to loop three different pages. Consider my faulty approach as a placeholder.

> ***How can I use format within dict in order to change page numbers?***

Working script (if I get rid of the pagination loop):

```
import requests

link = 'https://nsv3auess7-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/idealist7-production/query?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20vanilla%20JavaScript%203.30.0&x-algolia-application-id=NSV3AUESS7&x-algolia-api-key=c2730ea10ab82787f2f3cc961e8c1e06'

for page in range(0,3):
    payload = {"params":"getRankingInfo=true&clickAnalytics=true&facets=*&hitsPerPage=20&page={}&attributesToSnippet=%5B%22description%3A20%22%5D&attributesToRetrieve=objectID%2Ctype%2Cpublished%2Cname%2Ccity%2Cstate%2Ccountry%2Curl%2CorgID%2CorgUrl%2CorgName%2CorgType%2CgroupID%2CgroupUrl%2CgroupName%2CisFullTime%2CremoteOk%2Cpaid%2ClocalizedStarts%2ClocalizedEnds%2C_geoloc&filters=(orgType%3A'NONPROFIT')%20AND%20type%3A'JOB'&aroundLatLng=40.7127837%2C%20-74.0059413&aroundPrecision=15000&minimumAroundRadius=16000&query="}
    res = requests.post(link,json=payload.format(page)).json()
    for item in res['hits']:
        print(item['name'])
```

I get an error when I run the script as it is:

```
res = requests.post(link,json=payload.format(page)).json()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format` is a string method. You should apply it to the string value of your `payload` instead:

```
payload = {"params":"getRankingInfo=true&clickAnalytics=true&facets=*&hitsPerPage=20&page={}&attributesToSnippet=%5B%22description%3A20%22%5D&attributesToRetrieve=objectID%2Ctype%2Cpublished%2Cname%2Ccity%2Cstate%2Ccountry%2Curl%2CorgID%2CorgUrl%2CorgName%2CorgType%2CgroupID%2CgroupUrl%2CgroupName%2CisFullTime%2CremoteOk%2Cpaid%2ClocalizedStarts%2ClocalizedEnds%2C_geoloc&filters=(orgType%3A'NONPROFIT')%20AND%20type%3A'JOB'&aroundLatLng=40.7127837%2C%20-74.0059413&aroundPrecision=15000&minimumAroundRadius=16000&query=".format(page)}
res = requests.post(link,json=payload).json()
```